# Displaying the row count from mysql into a textview in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, rows

I am trying to retrieve the row count from a mysql database and display it into a textview in android. I have the following php file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

mysql_select_db('valetdb', $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(*) FROM drivers where datetimeparkreq is not null");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Total rows: " . $total;

?>
```

I was hoping to get the data from the line "$total = $row[0];". Since it does hold the count of rows. I am still learning about this whole json android php connection thing. So I would appreciate if someone will aid me! Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: For getting MySQL rows do you use any Arraylist or list?

Comment: No I don't actually. I was actually planning to get the $total variable I guess, but I welcome any suggestions, I am new to php as well. Then I am planning to use namevaluePairs to pass along the data between android and php, if that does make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Paolo,
  As the comments suggest, you should use something like the mysqli commands rather than mysql commands in php.  The mysqli command to get the number of rows in a query result is mysqli_num_rows().
  If you are looking to send this information to an Android app, the json format is very convenient to use.  If you are sending just one piece of data, you could use php code like:

echo "{numrows:";

echo $total . "}";

On the android side you would use HttpURLConnection and related routines to send a get request to the website and JsonReader routines to parse the json object sent from the website.
  Hopefully this helps you get started on communicating with your website.

Mike Kagan